# Can I connect to a remote sqlite binary dump file?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, mysql

I try to connect to a remote sqlite file and when I try to open the file I get an error:

```
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

...

}else {
    // Even though the open failed, call close to properly clean up resources.
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
}
```

When I try to output the database path, it gives the correct url ( it's a local network setup and the app connects to a static ip, searching for the binary sqlite dump )

2010-04-27 12:47:43.017 bbc_v1[4904:207] loading db path: http://192.168.2.10:8888/bbc.sqlite

Tested and the file exists..

Is it possible to connect to a remote sqlite file? Or is this only possible when it's inside the app bundle?

Greets, Thomas

Comment: You don't want to open a SQL file that's in the app bundle. You would only be able to read from it and not write. Typically you copy your DB from the app bundle on first launch to the Documents directory and from then on open it from there.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3_open take a FILE name, not a URL.

I don't think sqlite do provide any remote access as it is explicitly designed for embedded use.

You should download your file and save it on the device, then open it.